# Repeat element from a 2D matrix to a 3D matrix with numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-D numpy matrix, an example

```
M = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

I would like, starting from M, to have a matrix like:

```
M = np.matrix([[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]],[[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]],[[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]])
```

thus, the new matrix has 3 dimensions. How can I do?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

NumPy matrix class can't hold `3D` data. So, assuming you are okay with NumPy array as output, we can extend the array version of it to `3D` with `None/np.newaxis` and then use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
np.repeat(np.asarray(M)[:,None],3,axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [233]: M = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])

In [234]: np.repeat(np.asarray(M)[:,None],3,axis=1)
Out[234]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [5, 6],
        [5, 6]]])
```

Alternatively, with [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) -

```
np.tile(np.asarray(M),3).reshape(-1,3,M.shape[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
np.array([list(np.array(i)) * 3 for i in M])
```

Answer (score 0):

as another answerer already said, the matrix can't be three-dimensional. 
instead of it, you can make 3-dimensional `np.array` like below.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
M = np.array(M)
M = np.array([ [x, x, x] for x in M])
M
```